# C++ inserting array values into another array, but combining similar values into the same elements

Tags: c++, arrays, counter

So far I have gotten most of my functions working. I am now stuck on my final step. I need to take in an array from my main, to my "histo" function. I need to take repeating values within certain ranges, and put them each into the same array element and count them. Once this is done, I am to print out a histogram with asterisks. the ranges are------bin 0. if score < 10.----bin 1. if score >= 10 but < 20......ect. Then the output;       9| ** 8|* 7| ***  and so on until 0. The asterisks need to resemble the amount of numbers that fit within the specified range and stored in an array element. I am stuck on this part and we can't use vectors, or any #includes other than , ,  and using namespace std; Any advice is great. I have my cout in the main to make sure my math was correct.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

/*int histo(int x);*/
double dev(int count, int* scores, double mn);
double mean(int count, int* stats);

int main()
{
    int scores[101];
    int count = 0;
    int bin[10];
    double mn;

    cout << "Enter a score (-1 to stop): ";

    do
    {
        cin >> scores[count++];
    } while (scores[count - 1] != -1);
    count--;
    mn = mean(count, scores);
    cout << "mean: " << mean(count, scores) << endl;
    cout << "dev: " << dev(count, scores, mn) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int histo(int* scores)
{
    int bins[10]{};
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < *scores; i++)
    {
        if (*scores < 10)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 10 && *scores < 20)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 20 && *scores < 30)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 30 && *scores < 40)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 40 && *scores < 50)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 50 && *scores < 60)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 60 && *scores < 70)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 80 && *scores < 90)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        else if (*scores >= 90)
        {
            bins[counter++];
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < )
    }
}

double dev(int count, int* scores, double mn)
{
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    double d = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        x = pow(scores[i] - mn, 2);
        y += x;
    }
    d = sqrt(y / count);
    return d;
}
double mean(int count, int* scores)
{
    double total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        total += scores[i];
    }

    return total / count;
}
```

I know I went over kill with the if statements. This is just where I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: 'else' already implies that scores bigger or equal than the previous statement. Also dereferencing scores pointer doesn't indicate the end of the array. You almost have it with what you have now

Comment: If you do however stay within bounds of scores, you will go out of bounds on bins, since you increase the counter everytime it hits any statement. So in other words, your current solution is very full with undefined behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < *scores; i++)
```

Ok, so scores is a pointer to an array. By de-referencing it you get the value of the first element of that array, but not the count/size of it.

```
 if (*scores < 10)
 {
    bins[counter++];
 }
 else if (*scores >= 10 && *scores < 20)
 {
    bins[counter++];
 }
```

bins[counter++] will go out of bounds very soon with this setup, since your scores array is > 10 (not taking the undefined behaviour into account). Also the else statement already implies that *scores >= the previous statement.

So the solution to this will be something like this, assuming you want to increase the bin on index n every time:

```
int histo(int *scores, int scoreCount)
{
    int bins[9]{};

    for (int i = 0; i < scoreCount; i++)
    {
        if (scores[i] < 10)
        {
            bins[0]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 20)
        {
            bins[1]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 30)
        {
            bins[2]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 40)
        {
            bins[3]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 50)
        {
            bins[4]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 60)
        {
            bins[5]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 70)
        {
            bins[6]++;
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 90)
        {
            bins[7]++;
        }
        else
        {
            bins[8]++;
        }
    }

    // Do stuff with your bins
}
```

Comment: This helped out a ton. I was mistaken on my next steps to take. My histo function is just to recreate the bins array like you have shown. Makes sense, I don't know why I didn't think about going out of bounds the way I did it before. So this worked out great. I am supposed to now pass this array from this function to the main function and then print the array in a histogram style layout. I know it requires to use two for loops, but I am having issues figuring out how to pass the array back to main.

Comment: You either allocate new memory in the `histo` function and return that (don't forget to delete it) or you pass in the `bins` as an argument to the function. I suggest the first option, since in-case you change the scoring mechanism you can't forget to increase/decrease the size of the `bins` array.

Comment: @J_Roost312 so that would look something like this: `int *bins = new int[9];` And then just return that. And when you're done with it you call `delete[] bins;`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're making the histo function a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

```
void histo(int* scores)
{
    int bins[10] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; scores[i] != -1 ; i++)
    {
        int index = scores[i]/10;
        bins[index]++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << i + 1;
        for(int j = 0; j < bins[i]; j++){
            cout << "*";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that the last entry of the scores array == -1. I don't see anywhere in OP's code that this is happening though.

Comment: @Neijwiert `while (scores[count - 1] != -1);`

Comment: Ok, I missed that. But that still expects the user to input -1 as his last score. This is just bad code practice IMO

Comment: @Neijwiert im just using the way he defined his input.

Comment: I see that, but that doesn't mean you can't give advice to what is just asking for undefined behaviour. You're also relying on scores being 0 to 9 in this case. But I think this confusion is also to blame on OP, since he/she is not really clear on what the desired output is.

Comment: Sorry, I was having a hard time showing the output through text. My main issue is the for loop. I knew those needed to happen, I just couldn't figure out how I would take each value and sort it into another array. The comments have helped.

Comment: I also need to group up the numbers as well. So for every 10 numbers, they group into the bin[10] for each division. If the user inputs 2 2 2 60 50 60 etc....it there would be 3 counts for bin[0] and 2 counts for bin[7] and 1 count for bin[6]

Comment: @J_Roost312 it kind of sounds like this is a school exercise. As you stated we already helped you go a long way, maybe its best you try to discover this yourself as SO isn't a coding service

Comment: I wouldn't have posted if I hadn't exhausted my resources. I was looking for hints rather than answers. This did help a long ways, and I have made it further than I was. Once I need a coding service i'll let you know.

Comment: Also, that sounded rude. Wasn't meant to be. I am just not looking for handouts, but primarily other perspectives on the program. My professor pretty much has us learn out of a book, and there is only so much I can figure out from the text.